# Populating a table with 2 columns of data and returning a yes or no

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

Need to know how to populate E3:G8 where if the person's name has the letter next to their name then it returns "yes" and if the letter isn't next to the person's name then it returns a "no"? Thanks

[image]

Comment: (1) Please try to explain your problem more clearly.  Show the result you expect.  (2) Try to solve this yourself, and describe what you tried and where you got stuck.    Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [COUNTIFS()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-countifs-function).

This formula, filled right and down from E3, gives the results shown below.

`=IF(COUNTIFS($A$3:$A$11,$D3,$B$3:$B$11,E$2)>0,"Yes","No")`

[image]

The `COUNTIFS()` portion of the formula counts how many times column A has the name listed in column D, **and** column B has the letter listed in row 2.  The `IF()` checks whether this count is > 0, and returns either "Yes" or "No".